# R - Quick question about narrowing plot of the forest plot using metafor package; too wide

Tags: r, width, r-forestplot, metafor

With the help of some kind individuals, I was able to transform the proportions in my forest plot to percentages through the metafor package.

I believe I have one issue left with my forest plot, and that's the width. As you can see in photo, **the plot of the data in the middle is just WAY too wide; it's taking up 2/3 of the picture's space**.

--- How can I narrow this plot, and at the same time **reduce the amount of gap** there is between the text columns (e.g., "Study", "Events", Total") and the plot?

[image]

*Please disregard the blue boxes; I'm just blurring out the data because it's not relevant here. Essentially, what you can see is that I have three columns on the left: Study, Events and Total, and two columns on the right: Weight and % [95% CI]*

Here's the code I have so far

```
forest(dat.back$yi, ci.lb=dat.back$ci.lb, ci.ub=dat.back$ci.ub, psize=1, xlab = "CNCP Prevalence (%)", slab = Study.Name, atransf = mytransf, xlim = c(-0.35,1.05), ylim = c(-1.5,16), header = c("Study", "Weight       %    [95% CI]"), refline = 0.399, digits = 1, ilab = cbind(dat.back$xi, dat.back$ni, dat.back$wt), ilab.xpos = c(-0.15, -0.05, 0.88), at = c(0.10, 0.40, 0.70))

text(c(-0.15, -0.05), 15, c("Events", "Total"), font= 2)
text(c(-0.15, -0.05), -0.5, c("108293", "224624"), font = 1)
text(c(0.88), -0.5, c("100%"), font = 1)

addpoly(pred$pred, ci.lb=pred$ci.lb, ci.ub=pred$ci.ub, row=-0.5, digits=1, mlab="Total (RE Model)", efac=1.5, atransf = mytransf, cex = 1.00)

text(-0.35, -1.5, pos = 4, cex = 1.00, bquote(paste(tau^2, " = ", .(formatC(res$tau2, digits = 2, format = "f")), " , ", I^2, " = ", .(formatC(res$I2, digits = 2, format = "f")), " , ", chi^2, " = ", .(formatC(res$QE, digits = 1, format = "f")), " , ", p, " = ", .(formatC(res$QEp, digits=4, format="f")))))
```

Here's what I  get when I use str() for my forest plot:

```
List of 8
 $ xlim    : num [1:2] -0.35 1.05
 $ alim    : num [1:2] 0.1 0.7
 $ at      : num [1:7] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7
 $ ylim    : num [1:2] -3 17
 $ rows    : int [1:13] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ cex     : num 1
 $ cex.lab : num 1
 $ cex.axis: num 1
```

Would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

You have the `plotwidth` argument that will reduce the forest plot with for exemple : `plotwidth=unit(10, "mm")`. Also, add the `colgap` (you can adjust the number to fit what you want) :

```
forest(dat.back$yi, ci.lb=dat.back$ci.lb, ci.ub=dat.back$ci.ub, psize=1, xlab = "CNCP Prevalence (%)", slab = Study.Name, atransf = mytransf, xlim = c(-0.35,1.05), ylim = c(-1.5,16), header = c("Study", "Weight       %    [95% CI]"), refline = 0.399, digits = 1, ilab = cbind(dat.back$xi, dat.back$ni, dat.back$wt), ilab.xpos = c(-0.15, -0.05, 0.88), at = c(0.10, 0.40, 0.70),plotwidth=unit(10, "mm"),colgap =unit(2, "mm"))
```

Comment: This sounds like a fantastic idea. The problem is that I'm getting an error saying: ``` 50: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "colgap.forest.right" is not a graphical parameter ``` ; and another error ``` saying: 49: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "colgap.forest.left" is not a graphical parameter ```

Comment: Yes you're right, `colgap.forest.right` is for the `forest.meta()` function, I just updated with the `colgap` parameter for the `forest` function

Comment: None of this will work. The `forest()` function being used comes from the `metafor` package, not the `meta` package. For the former, you should play around with the `xlim` argument.